# Add dynamic property into a DataTable and be readable in intellisense

Tags: c#, reflection, datatable, intellisense

I want to know if exists some method to implement dynamically a property into a DataTable and be readable in IntelliSense.

```
DataTable dtMethods = new DataTable();

dtMethods.Columns.Add("Project");
dtMethods.Columns.Add("Method");
dtMethods.Columns.Add("Code_method");
dtMethods.Columns.Add("Params", typeof(Object[]));

dtMethods.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Project 1", "Method 123", "CallExample", null });
dtMethods.AddDynamicPropertyIntoDataTable("Project"); // Method that I want to create
// AddDynamicPropertyIntoDataTable(dtMethods, "Project"); // Or something like that

dtMethods.Rows[0].Project; // Using example - That can be readable by IntelliSense
```

I don't know if exists some other way to implement this action without adding a Dynamic Property.

[Edited]:

My goal is achieve a method to ask for specific column for specific row in a DataTable. Without using the 'classic' method:

```
dtMethods.Rows[1]["Project"] = "";
```

Instead, use the following method:

```
dtMethods.Rows[1].Project = "";
string myValue = dtMethods.Rows[1].Project;
```

Comment: you can't do that. The nature of that "stringly typed" kind of things is that you don't know anything about them until runtime. The solution is to stop using glorified dictionaries and create a proper strongly typed data model that represents all your domain entities.

Comment: Please explain what is your goal, we can give you workaround. This is not going to work !

Comment: @HighCore Yes, that is my first option. I just want to know if exists some dynamic method to create and access to properties in a class (In this case a DataTable)

Comment: @MiBol no there isn't. I suppose you can use Roslyn to create a custom intellisense feature based on your domain model, but I never tried that and Roslyn hasn't been released officially yet.